# No text console with custom kernel

Tags: kernel, graphics, virtual-console, framebuffer

I've recently started using my own custom kernels in Ubuntu, and they are working without problems, with the exception that I don't have a text console when I press any of the key combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>. I'm only seeing the Ubuntu splash screen. I thought it has something to do with the graphics settings in the kernel configuration under *Device drivers* -> *Graphics support*, particularly the *Frame buffer* settings. I have everything activated which is active in the kernel provided by Ubuntu, except for the fb drivers for specific chipsets other than `nvidiafb`, since I have an Nvidia card. Here are the enabled settings:

```
CONFIG_FB=y
CONFIG_FB_CMDLINE=y
CONFIG_FB_NOTIFY=y
CONFIG_FB_DDC=m
CONFIG_FB_BOOT_VESA_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_FILLRECT=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_COPYAREA=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT=y
CONFIG_FB_SYS_FILLRECT=m
CONFIG_FB_SYS_COPYAREA=m
CONFIG_FB_SYS_IMAGEBLIT=m
CONFIG_FB_SYS_FOPS=m
CONFIG_FB_DEFERRED_IO=y
CONFIG_FB_BACKLIGHT=y
CONFIG_FB_MODE_HELPERS=y
CONFIG_FB_TILEBLITTING=y
CONFIG_FB_VESA=y
CONFIG_FB_EFI=y
CONFIG_FB_NVIDIA=m
CONFIG_FB_NVIDIA_I2C=y
CONFIG_FB_NVIDIA_BACKLIGHT=y
```

I wonder which kernel setting is responsible for the text console. My policy of configuring my own kernel was to disable everything I assumed I don't need, especially all the loadable kernel modules for specific devices that are included in the house kernel. Of course, I left many options unchanged as I didn't have a clue what they were about.

For my custom kernels, I have always been using the latest kernel source depended upon by the `linux-source` package, which currently is in version `4.15.0-45.48` from January 29. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

**Update:** I compiled a new kernel with the option `CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y`. With this kernel, I do have a text console, however, the proprietary Nvidia driver I've been using isn't loaded. What do I need to do to have that driver for my new kernel?

Answer (score 0):

It works! I had to include the kernel option

```
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y
```

After booting the new kernel, however, the proprietary Nvidia driver wasn't present. I had to do a

```
dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-dkms-390
```

in order to build that driver for my kernel. That also build the module `nvidia.ko` for the generic kernel, which surprises me, as that kernel did already use the driver `nvidia`. Now I'm wondering where that kernel module was located if was not in `/lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko`?